# How to add a tag in front of a sass rule?

Tags: css, sass, css-selectors

I have this scss:

```
.nav {
    &__item {
        color: black;
    }
}
```

This compiles to:

```
.nav__item
```

Is it possible to modify the above sccs so that it compiles with a tag in front of it, like the following?

```
a.nav__item
```

OR

```
li.nav_item
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way using @at-root. This way avoids having to declare `&__item` twice.

```
.nav {
  &__item {
    color: black;
    
    @at-root {
      ul#{&} {
        display: block;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Complies to

```
.nav__item {
  color: black;
}
ul.nav__item {
  display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.nav {
  a#{&}__item {
    color: black;
  }
}
```

Output

```
.nav a.nav__item {
  color: black;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Even though this is possible using

```
.nav {
  a#{&}__item {
    color: black;
  }
}
```

I would highly encourage you to write it like this

```
a,
li {
  &.nav {
    &__item {
      color: black;
    }
  } 
}
```